# Adding new function to an existing R package

Tags: r, r-package

I made a new R Package a few days ago. I want to add a new function to it. I couldn't really find any proper documentation for this. Most of the documentation is for if you want to create an R Package from scratch. The output of log is:

```
* using R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
* using platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32 (64-bit)
* using session charset: ISO8859-1
* using options '--no-manual --as-cran'
* checking for file 'dpnsh/DESCRIPTION' ... OK
* checking extension type ... Package
* this is package 'dpnsh' version '0.1.0'
* package encoding: UTF-8
* checking package namespace information ... OK
* checking package dependencies ... ERROR
Namespace dependency not required: 'head'

See section 'The DESCRIPTION file' in the 'Writing R Extensions'
manual.
* DONE
Status: 1 ERROR
```

When I execute "Check Package" this is what I get:

```
checking package dependencies ... ERROR
  Namespace dependency not required: 'head'
  See section 'The DESCRIPTION file' in the 'Writing R Extensions'
  manual.

1 error x | 0 warnings v | 0 notes v
Error: R CMD check found ERRORs
Execution halted

Exited with status 1.


* using R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)
* using platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32 (64-bit)
```

My R Script looks like:

```
#' Gives a count of missing values in each column
#' @param dataset object
#' @return Count of missing values in each column of the dataframe
#' @export
nullvalues = function(dataset) {
aa = c()
bb = c()
for (count in 1:length(dataset)) {
  aa <- append(aa,colnames(dataset)[count])
  bb <- append(bb,sum(is.na(dataset[colnames(dataset)[count]])))
}
missing_values=NULL
missing_values$columns <- aa
missing_values$missing_values_count <- bb
missing_values <- data.frame(missing_values)
knitr::kable(missing_values)

}

#' Evaluates the forecasting accuracy for a ts object
#' @param datasetname object
#' @param split_ratio numeric - should be between 0 and 1
#' @importFrom head meanf tail naive snaive rwf accuracy
#' @return
#' @export
method_error = function(datasetname,split_ratio=0.75){
  ifelse(
    split_ratio>=1,
    print("Please try again with a number less than 1"),split_ratio)
  train = head(datasetname, split_ratio*length(datasetname))
  test = tail(datasetname, (1-split_ratio)*length(datasetname))
  Mean = meanf(train, length(test))
  Naive = naive(train,length(test))
  Snaive = snaive(train,length(test))
  Drift = rwf(train, length(test), drift=T)

  accuracy_meanf = accuracy(Mean, test)[2,c(2:6)]
  accuracy_naive = accuracy(Naive, test)[2,c(2:6)]
  accuracy_snaive = accuracy(Snaive, test)[2,c(2:6)]
  accuracy_drift = accuracy(Drift, test)[2,c(2:6)]
  knitr::kable(data.frame(accuracy_meanf, accuracy_naive,accuracy_snaive, accuracy_drift))
}
```

The namespace file looks like:

```
# Generated by roxygen2: do not edit by hand

export(method_error)
export(nullvalues)
importFrom(head,accuracy)
importFrom(head,meanf)
importFrom(head,naive)
importFrom(head,rwf)
importFrom(head,snaive)
importFrom(head,tail)
```

And the description file looks like:

```
Package: dpnsh
Type: Package
Title: Generic stuff
Version: 0.1.0
Author: Deepansh Arora
Maintainer: The package maintainer <dpnsharr@gmail.com>
Description: More about what it does (maybe more than one line)
    Use four spaces when indenting paragraphs within the Description.
License: GPL-3
Imports: knitr, forecast
Encoding: UTF-8
LazyData: true
RoxygenNote: 7.1.1
```

Please guide me on how I can fix this issue.
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, could you provide how you created your first package ? Is there any github with your packages files for us to see ? Have you tried adding your function on the same script or another script in the R directory ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is the issue, but maybe the package imports need to be on individual lines? I'm not sure if this is a style thing, but I've only seen Imports listed this way.

Comment: Also, are you trying to actually import functions from a package called head? the first string after `#' @importFrom` should be the name of the package. I only ask because I've never heard of a package called `head`, only the generic function.